# What is the meaning of this line "ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = "

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm wondering, what is the meaning of the following line. What is the `<String>` part mean?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
```

Here's the full line of code.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ExternalData.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);
```

Comment: Why are you writing Android apps if you don't know the basic features of Java yet?

Comment: Its object type hold by ArraryAdapter.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Generics are not basic features. They were added quite recently to the Java and most of the people don't even know what they are and what are they used for. You can still code without them and have your code compile normally.

Comment: @Tomislav: According to Wikipedia generics were added almost ten years ago. If your knowledge is that much out of date, you ought to be ashamed of yourself. Or is that the standard in the Java world?

Comment: I do know how to write program in Java, but I'm a bit confuse in the above line format, that's why I was asking if anyone can help and explain to me.

Comment: @fkaufusi Take a basic android or java tutorial then come back.

Comment: @Matti Well, since I know what Generics are, my knowledge is obivously not out of date. But also, since I'm still working on projects that are running on Java 1.4 so I do know that Generics are not vital to have your code run normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<String>` part of it all means that the `ArrayAdapter` will be working with `String[]` data (the `paths` parameter). In other words, each element in the array will be a `String`.

Comment: Thanks so much ninetwozero, now I understand. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

These kinds of statements are called **generics**. You are going to need a decent knowledge of these since the Android framework uses them heavily.

Briefly, In this particular instance, The `ArrayAdapter` can be used with many different types of objects. The statement `ArrayAdapter<String>` means that the `ArrayAdapter` is going to be used with the type string.

Here's a simple beginners tutorial on generics in java:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html

Go through it and come back if you have more questions. Good luck!